# Matlab: delete empty spaces in a string

Tags: string, matlab

I have a 400 x 8 char in which I would like to delete empty spaces. I have numbers like this:

1, 99278; 4, 99378; 1,101283;

I would need to have:

1,99278; 4,99378; 1,101283;

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you want to remove spaces after commas, but not after semicolons. You can do that easily with [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
>> str = '1, 99278; 4,  99378; 1,101283;';
>> result = regexprep(str, ',\s+', ',');
result =
1,99278; 4,99378; 1,101283;
```

Comment: +1. I knew this was coming :-) ... I really have to learn the regular expression syntax. Every time I put that for later ... but it could have saved me so much time already

Comment: The trick (for me at least) is _not_ to learn it. You already have a general feeling of what can be done with regular expressions. When you feel your problem can be solved with them, just check Matlab's help on `regexp`, which contains the basic (or look for something more advanced). Soon you'll find you are familiar with the things you use most

Comment: Because I had it in 400 x 8 char, i needed to transform it with: str=cellstr(character); afterwards it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The function [isspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/isspace.html) is your friend.

```
myString( isspace(myString) ) = [] ;
strrep( myString, ';' , '; ') ;
```

The first line is enough if you don't need a space after the `;`. If you want to keep this space, run the second line too.

Answer (score 2):

Another form to invoke `strrep` function:

```
strrep(string,' ','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stringWithoutSpaces = originalString(~isspace(originalString))
```